# Problems writing Ascii values to Serial port through VBA

Tags: vba, serial-port, ascii

I am trying to integrate Excel with some scales.  The scales use serial ports to communicate.  I can read just fine but I need to send commands the scale.  Here are the read and the write functions.

```
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' CommRead - Read serial port input buffer.
'
' Parameters:
'   intPortID   - Port ID used when port was opened.
'   strData     - Data buffer.
'   lngSize     - Maximum number of bytes to be read.
'
' Returns:
'   Error Code  - 0 = No Error.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CommRead(intPortID As Integer, strData As String, _
    lngSize As Long) As Long

Dim lngStatus As Long
Dim lngRdSize As Long, lngBytesRead As Long
Dim lngRdStatus As Long, strRdBuffer As String * 1024
Dim lngErrorFlags As Long, udtCommStat As COMSTAT

    On Error GoTo Routine_Error

    strData = ""
    lngBytesRead = 0
    DoEvents

    ' Clear any previous errors and get current status.
    lngStatus = ClearCommError(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, lngErrorFlags, _
        udtCommStat)

    If lngStatus = 0 Then
        lngBytesRead = -1
        lngStatus = SetCommError("CommRead (ClearCommError)")
        GoTo Routine_Exit
    End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'    If udtCommStat.cbInQue > 0 Then
'        If udtCommStat.cbInQue > lngSize Then
'            lngRdSize = udtCommStat.cbInQue
'        Else
'            lngRdSize = lngSize
'        End If
'    Else
'        lngRdSize = 0
'    End If
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    lngRdSize = lngSize
    If lngRdSize Then
        lngRdStatus = ReadFile(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, strRdBuffer, _
            lngRdSize, lngBytesRead, udtCommOverlap)

        If lngRdStatus = 0 Then
            lngStatus = GetLastError
            If lngStatus = ERROR_IO_PENDING Then
                ' Wait for read to complete.
                ' This function will timeout according to the
                ' COMMTIMEOUTS.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant variable.
                ' Every time it times out, check for port errors.

                ' Loop until operation is complete.
                While GetOverlappedResult(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, _
                    udtCommOverlap, lngBytesRead, True) = 0

                    lngStatus = GetLastError

                    If lngStatus <> ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE Then
                        lngBytesRead = -1
                        lngStatus = SetCommErrorEx( _
                            "CommRead (GetOverlappedResult)", _
                            udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle)
                        GoTo Routine_Exit
                    End If
                Wend
            Else
                ' Some other error occurred.
                lngBytesRead = -1
                lngStatus = SetCommErrorEx("CommRead (ReadFile)", _
                    udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle)
                GoTo Routine_Exit

            End If
        End If

        strData = Left$(strRdBuffer, lngBytesRead)
    End If

Routine_Exit:
    CommRead = lngBytesRead
    Exit Function

Routine_Error:
    lngBytesRead = -1
    lngStatus = Err.Number
    With udtCommError
        .lngErrorCode = lngStatus
        .strFunction = "CommRead"
        .strErrorMessage = Err.Description
    End With
    Resume Routine_Exit
End Function

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' CommWrite - Output data to the serial port.
'
' Parameters:
'   intPortID   - Port ID used when port was opened.
'   strData     - Data to be transmitted.
'
' Returns:
'   Error Code  - 0 = No Error.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CommWrite(intPortID As Integer, strData As String) As Long

Dim i As Integer
Dim lngStatus As Long, lngSize As Long
Dim lngWrSize As Long, lngWrStatus As Long

    On Error GoTo Routine_Error

    ' Get the length of the data.
    lngSize = Len(strData)

    ' Output the data.
    lngWrStatus = WriteFile(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, strData, lngSize, _
        lngWrSize, udtCommOverlap)

    ' Note that normally the following code will not execute because the driver
    ' caches write operations. Small I/O requests (up to several thousand bytes)
    ' will normally be accepted immediately and WriteFile will return true even
    ' though an overlapped operation was specified.

    DoEvents

    If lngWrStatus = 0 Then
        lngStatus = GetLastError
        If lngStatus = 0 Then
            GoTo Routine_Exit
        ElseIf lngStatus = ERROR_IO_PENDING Then
            ' We should wait for the completion of the write operation so we know
            ' if it worked or not.
            '
            ' This is only one way to do this. It might be beneficial to place the
            ' writing operation in a separate thread so that blocking on completion
            ' will not negatively affect the responsiveness of the UI.
            '
            ' If the write takes long enough to complete, this function will
            ' timeout
            ' according to the CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant variable.
            ' At that time we can check for errors and then wait some more.

            ' Loop until operation is complete.
            While GetOverlappedResult(udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle, _
                udtCommOverlap, lngWrSize, True) = 0

                lngStatus = GetLastError

                If lngStatus <> ERROR_IO_INCOMPLETE Then
                    lngStatus = SetCommErrorEx( _
                        "CommWrite (GetOverlappedResult)", _
                        udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle)
                    GoTo Routine_Exit
                End If
            Wend
        Else
            ' Some other error occurred.
            lngWrSize = -1

            lngStatus = SetCommErrorEx("CommWrite (WriteFile)", _
                udtPorts(intPortID).lngHandle)
            GoTo Routine_Exit

        End If
    End If

    For i = 1 To 10
        DoEvents
    Next

Routine_Exit:
    CommWrite = lngWrSize
    Exit Function

Routine_Error:
    lngStatus = Err.Number
    With udtCommError
        .lngErrorCode = lngStatus
        .strFunction = "CommWrite"
        .strErrorMessage = Err.Description
    End With
    Resume Routine_Exit
End Function
```

It might just be the way I'm trying to input the string as Ascii.  Here are the instructions from the manual for giving commands:

Commands sent to the balance comprise one or more characters of the ASCII character set. Here, the following must be noted:
 Enter commands only in uppercase. Nevertheless, units have to be capitalized properly.
 The possible parameters of the command must be separated from one another and from the command name by a
space (ASCII 32 dec., in this manual represented as ).
 The possible input for "text" is a sequence of characters of the 8-bit ASCII character set from 32 dec. to 255 dec.
 Each command must be closed by CR LF (ASCII 13 dec., 10 dec.).

If I wanted to send the "Z" Command, would I be sending 901310 in this format?

```
Private Sub GetWeight1_Click()
Dim intPortID As Integer ' Ex. 1, 2, 3, 4 for COM1 - COM4
    Dim lngStatus As Long
    Dim lngWrStatus As Long
    Dim strData   As String
    Dim lngSize As Long


    intPortID = 4

    strData = "901310"
    lngWrStatus = CommWrite(intPortID, strData)
    'lngStatus = CommRead(intPortID, strData, 12)
```

Maybe the code is good but the string is not.  I did not write this code but the read function is working well.  I just can't get the write function to operate.  Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you just send a `"Z" & vbCrLf` to send a "Z"?  The function comments don't make it look like you need to convert the hex representation of a character to a two-byte character - you just pass the function the character itself.

Comment: This totally works!  Completely overlooked the simple answer!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the device you supplied, and my understanding of what the posted code does, it would seem that the necessary information to be written in order to send a "Z" command would be "Z" followed by a CR/LF combination, i.e. use

```
strData = "Z" & vbCrLF
```

or (if you want to avoid the built-in constant)

```
strData = "Z" & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
```